# Field Type Conversion-Conversion Tab-StreamSets

Tags: java, csv, cassandra, streamsets

When I am trying to do type conversion, "by field name" conversion method. When I click on `field to convert` there is an automatic drop down list which show list of data content from the source(CSV file). The list showing both `/0 [0] ,/1 [1]`. Why it is showing both and what is that mean?
The screen shot of the StreamSets is here: [StreamSets-Field Conversion-Cassandra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adrX4.jpg)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow... can you please show us code...

Comment: i've always wondered this too.  as you add fields, it adds the bracketed suggestions in increasing order to the dropdown.  however, can't see how this is ever useful as you must use the /0, /1 notation with the expression language.  Probably just a glitch that the suggestion dropdown shows map-list positions too.